# How to get list of all technologies

Tags: autocomplete, stackexchange, stackexchange-api

If you look at the 'Tags' option when you post a question, it gives an auto-complete/intellisense-assist when we type a tag, say SQL Server, for example. I need to get the whole list of technologies, the itemsSource, of this intellisense-assist. You may see a similar use-case in LinkedIn when we try to add a technology/skill that we learnt, to our profile. Can someone please tell me the source from which we may get this whole list of technolgies?

Comment: is the tag 'Ontology' relevant to this question?

Comment: May be not, but I couldn't find a closer one. In computer-science, ontology represents a set of concepts inter-related to each other. What I am looking for is a concept-graph with technologies as nodes, and hence found the naming meaningful. pls let me know if you any better suggestions.

Comment: I like the answer provided by jkbkot and the edit by RobV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like

`http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags`

which gives:

```
{
"total": 35690,
"page": 1,
"pagesize": 70,
"tags": [
{
"name": "c#",
"count": 576794,
"fulfills_required": false
},
{
"name": "java",
"count": 554383,
"fulfills_required": false
},
{
"name": "javascript",
"count": 523194,
"fulfills_required": false
},
...
```

Have a look at [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage)